# Invoking YUI's delegate method using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui, dhtml

I have YUI2's delegate defined as

```
<div id="container">
    <ul id="list">
        <li id="li-1">List Item 1</li>
        <li id="li-2">List Item 2</li>
        <li id="li-3">List Item 3</li>
        <li id="li-4">List Item 4</li>
        <li id="li-5">List Item 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    var foo = function() {
        alert("clicked");
    };

    var Dom = YAHOO.util.Dom, Event = YAHOO.util.Event;

    Event.delegate("container", "click", foo, "li");

    // jQuery code
    $("#li-5").click();

</script>
```

When I click on the **li**, alert shown, that is expected. But why the jQuery **click**() method does not work? Or what is the correct way to simulate the click() delegate?

I have prepare a Live URL for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/ngRvw/

**Updates:**
I need the alert automatically execute like this one: http://jsfiddle.net/ngRvw/3/ But I need to preserve the original YUI's delegate

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you are combining those two? jQuery has a delegate method on his own http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ now called 'on' http://api.jquery.com/on/ on newer versions

Comment: and here it is without YUI: http://jsfiddle.net/ngRvw/3/

Comment: Your fiddle works perfectly fine in Chrome browser. Are you testing in any other browser?

Comment: @mblase75 Your version without YUI is working, but I want to combine both jQuery and YUI.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli, my version is not working as  the auto alert is not triggered. The pure jQuery version by mblase75 works, but without mixing YUI, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/ngRvw/3/